# How to Add Multiple case condtion in kibana data table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

```
select name,date,offer_name ,channel,
       sum(case
             when status = '1' then
              1
             else
              0
           end) Active
       sum(case
             when t.status = '2' then
              1
             else
              0
           end) InActive
       count(offer_name) as count

  from table
```

I want to achieve above query in **kibana** data table to display data